# How to center my UILableView within a parent RoundedRectView in code?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a RoundedRectView with a UILabel that holds lines of text of varying length separated by \n. Once I set the text on the label, I do a

[self.messageLabel sizeToFit];

which causes the multiple lines of text to be shown properly HOWEVER the label is no longer at the center of the parent view (RoundedRectView)

How can I then center the UILabelView within the RoundedRectView ?

Thanks

Comment: Is the label not centered, or is the text not centered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
labelView.center = CGPointMake(roundedRectView.center.x,roundedRectView.center.y);
```